# Force lint to check translations on exact languages

Tags: android, android-lint

I get this error:

> "preferences_default_reminder_labels" is not translated in cs, de, es,
>   fr, it, ja, ko, nl, pl, pt, pt-rBR, zh
>
> Issue: Checks for incomplete translations where not all strings are
>   translated Id: MissingTranslation

But my app needs to be translated in english and russian only. How can I tune lint to check only en,ru translations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Lint limit languages to check for missing translations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232728/android-lint-limit-languages-to-check-for-missing-translations)

Answer (score 0):

If you have empty folders in `res` called `values-XX` for languages other then `ru` delete them.

Comment: I have not any other folders only "values" and "values-ru"

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set environmental variable `ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS`.

From [lint docs](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks):

> MissingTranslation
>
> ---
>
> Summary: Checks for incomplete translations where not all strings are translated
>
> Priority: 8 / 10
>   Severity: Fatal
>   Category: Correctness:Messages
>
> If an application has more than one locale, then all the strings
>   declared in one language should also be translated in all other
>   languages.
>
> By default this detector allows regions of a language to just provide
>   a subset of the strings and fall back to the standard language
>   strings. You can require all regions to provide a full translation by
>   setting the environment variable ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS.

What is environmental variable and how to use them you can find [here](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).

Comment: It looks like ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS does not have any influence on MissingTranslation. By the way it does not helped me

Comment: Then just call from command line `$ lint --disable MissingTranslation /folder/with/project`. Or from Eclipse open project properties, choose Android Lint Preferences, find MissingTranslation (it is in the middle of list) and select Severity -> Ignore.

Comment: I don't want to disable MissingTranslation, I want to disable it only for languages other than ru,en

Comment: Perhaps your solution is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232728/android-lint-limit-languages-to-check-for-missing-translations