# Android language support: English only

Tags: android, eclipse, localization, multilingual, region

I published an application in English.
I do not have a plan for multi-language support yet, so the first version supports default language only.
I added ads(admob) for the second version, and localizations suddenly changed to default + 56 languages.
How can I change it back to default language only? Or is it okay to leave like that?

Comment: While I haven't used admob at all, I think since admob implements localization, it makes your app "support" those languages. It is okay to leave that, your app will still only display in English because you don't have other language resources for your app.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Andrew T. in the comment, it is quite possible that the admob library you have added is including the support for all languages, therefore you app is inheriting them.

I had the same problem, but thanks to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013558/2177061

I managed to solve it (I deleted the inappropriate res/*-* directories and the apk was not detected as multi-language anymore)

Hope this helps