# How can I recover R.java file

Tags: android, r.java-file, lint

My project was running properly.I just gave a Lint check and it gave me errors from all projects. So I just cleaned my project. But now its not generating R.java file. How can I recover it. I tried building..But its not working

Comment: try to clean project again..

Comment: check you problem window is show where exactly error.

Comment: Try to restart your eclipse.

Comment: i cleared errors given in the problems window.Now it has only this error:R cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you resource folder(`res/`), it is containing  error, Fix all error in `res/` folder. then clean up your workspace. and build the project again, it will works.

`R.java` is automatically regenerated for you as soon as your `res/` is corrected.

Comment: I didn't had any errors...i just gave Lint check and it gave me errors..So i cleaned it..it ws giving missing translations in the strings.xml file..How to add that?

Comment: I have used only values folder..I didn't make use of other language folder..Then why its giving errors?

Comment: can you post your string .xml

Answer (score 0):

My answer is assuming that you are using Eclipse. Cleaning a project deletes its bin and gen folders and rebuild them again. Don't clean while having errors in the project as it won't build R.java on cleaning. It will show a lot of R errors in project as R.java is no longer present. But it will be showing the actual error in the console window. Fix it and R will build automatically.

Comment: I didn't had any errors...i just gave Lint check and it gave me errors..So i cleaned it..it ws giving missing translations in the strings.xml file..How to add that?

Comment: Is there way to ignore them?

Comment: @user3698989 I don't know what errors you are getting. But if they came from the lint check, try removing it and build.

Comment: @user3698989 I don;t know about missing translaion errors, but heres a link. Maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232728/android-lint-limit-languages-to-check-for-missing-translations

Answer (score 0):

First you check Your *.XML files if there is any error If error then first solve it.

- Remove all import android.R from your activity
- Run Project->Clean it remove all auto generated files
- Build project using Project - Build Project it rebuild your project OR Checked Auto  Build ON
- Wait for a while it regenerate all files including R.java
- If steel R.java is not generate then it is problems related to Project Build Target
- Right click Project Go Properties->Android see in right section Project Build Target and see it match with your AndroidManifest.XML
- Make change accordingly and  repeat above steps

This one help you..